# Maven and m2e - build jar with dependencies information

Tags: java, maven, jar

We are using `Maven` and `m2e` tools for our development and today we encountered a problem.

One of our projects is small library that is required for other projects, so we packaged it into jar file and put in our private `Maven` repository.

For now, all of the jars that we put in this repository didn't have any external dependencies, but this library I mentioned uses some external jars.

Now, when I add information about this jar to other poms, this jar is downloaded from our private repository but Maven doesn't download dependencies needed by this jar.

I am wondering if I need to use some special target/add something to my `pom.xml` file that will inform `Maven` to include information about dependencies needed by this artifact.

EDIT:
Here is the workflow I perform when I upload jar to our private repository:

1.I generate jar file from `Eclipse` using `m2e`

2.`mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=<your_group_name> -DartifactId=<your_artifact_name> -Dversion=<snapshot> -Dfile=<path_to_your_jar_file> -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true -DcreateChecksum=true`

3.I copy folder created in my local repository to remote repository

Comment: do the other projects also use maven?

Comment: The correct way is to build your library an use a classical `mvn deploy` instead of manually installing the jar. The generated pom (see `-DgeneratePom=true`) will be the bare minimum and will *not* include the dependency information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your small library is a maven project as you state, there should be no reason to have eclipse build the jar and then use maven to install it and then manually copy to the remote repo.  Instead you should use m2e to run the deploy goal:

```
mvn deploy
```

That will cause the jar to get built and then install it directly into your local maven repo then deploy it to the remote repo.

In eclipse this can be accomplished by right clicking your project, choosing `Run As -> Maven Build...` then in the run configuration window for `Goals` input type `deploy` then click `Run`.  After this has been done once, you can just use `Run As -> Maven Build` to run the same config again.

Comment: After changing my target to deploy on remote repository my dependencies are downloaded as they should but there is small issue in m2e. When I expand `Maven Dependencies` in Eclipse I can see some jars (including those that should be added as dependency of my library), but library itself is showed as directory, do you know what can cause this?

Comment: @Andna, dependencies show as a folders if you are depending on a project in the same eclipse workspace that whose version is the current version.  If, for instance, you have `DependencyA` in your workspace at version `1.1.0-SNAPSHOT` and your project `ProjectA` in the same workspace depends on version `1.1.0-SNAPSHOT` it shows a folder, but if, instead, you depend on version `1.0.0` of `DependencyA`, it would show as a jar.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about this feature so to speak.

Answer (score 3):

I see you use `-DgeneratePom=true` during the installation of the jar file. What you need to do is create a `pom.xml` for your artifact. In the pom.xml, you can specify the dependencies that your jar file requires. When executing the `install:install` plugin goal, you use `-DpomFile=pom.xml` instead.

Comment: Why not just run `mvn deploy`?  He mentioned the library is a maven project itself...

Comment: @Lucas, good point. I did not pay attention that the library itself is a maven project too. I saw the install:install plugin is used manually and assumed that ithe jar file is provided by a non-maven project.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is to run `mvn deploy`

You have to setup the distribution repository to your private artifact manager (nexus or artifactory) in your settings.xml

see [this](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Distribution_Management) for more details